# How to check if user input is empty with bufio?

Tags: go

I'm new with Go syntax, just trying to pass an error if the user did not input anything...

[EDIT] I would like the following function to stop running if the user did not input anything, and print a log. My `if required && answer == ""`  statement doesn't seem to work as "You must enter a value." does not log when the user does not input anything.

```
func QAR(q string, r string, required bool) string {
  reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

  // Print the question
  fmt.Printf(q)
  answer, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

  // If the answer is empty, return a log
  if required && answer == "" {
    log.Fatal("You must enter a value.")

    // Can I just use return to block it?
    return
  }

  // Print the response with the answer
  if r != "" {
    fmt.Println(r, answer)
  }

  return answer
}
```

Comment: is there any reason you aren't changing the return type to also return an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical pattern in go is to return multiple values, the last of which is an error, if one occurred. So your function signature could look like this:

```
func QAR(q string, r string, required bool) (string, error)
```

And the return statements like this:

```
return "", fmt.Errorf("user provided no input")
// ...
return answer, nil
```

**[EDIT]**

Note that [`bufio.Reader.ReadString(...)`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) includes the delimiter, so you probably need to check if `answer == "\n"`.

Comment: Thanks, but the major issue seems to be `&& answer == ""` any idea what's wrong with this?

Comment: @AstenMies What issues do you have with it ? What do you do ? What happens ? What do you want to happen ?

Comment: @AstenMies nope, I have no idea what's wrong with that snippet. Can you update your question to explain what behavior you are seeking and why your sample code doesn't accomplish it?

Comment: Yep, I just updated my question. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Oh boy, thanks a ton, I don't know why I thought that delimiter would end-up in kind of a black hole in the process ;)